# How can we map one table to multiple tables with different columns in sink DB in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

how can we replicate data from one source table to two destination tables with different columns? In Azure data factory we have any in built services is there?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [column mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) of copy activity.

If you want to do this at the same time (in a single pipeline) you could use foreach activity and then pass different column mapping into the copy activity [with expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).

To make it simple, you could just use [copy data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool) to help you build the pipeline.

Comment: Hi Fang Liu,Thanks for your information, I am looking for.... if the records have countryname ='UK'. we need to replicate record to UK table if the countryName='US' need to replicate to US table. without stored procedure. Thanks

Comment: How about use a query to lookup all the Uk records first and then Us records. You could take a look of ADF lookup activity and foreach activity.

Comment: But be aware that lookup has some payload size limitation.